# Sostantivo per la virtù di sapere quando ritirarsi

Tags: word-choice

Esiste un sostantivo che descriva (possibilmente con accezione intrinsecamente positiva, piuttosto che neutra) una delle seguenti:

- la *virtù di sapere quando è opportuno desistere*?
- la *virtù di sapere quando è opportuno ritirarsi* (per esempio in senso militare)?

Entrambi i significati sono in qualche modo (piuttosto vago) ascrivibili alla *temperanza*, la quale tuttavia descrive più rigorosamente la moderazione in sé piuttosto che la conoscenza delle occasioni nelle quali moderarsi, e non coglie necessariamente il senso dell'interrompere un'azione che si prolunga nel tempo.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Mi hai fatto pensare al famoso articolo di Alpher, Bethe e Gamow!

Comment: @Charo grazie! Conoscevo l'"articolo alfabetico" ma devo dire che non ho colto il nesso XD Immagino ti riferisca al fatto che Bethe si sarebbe dovuto astenere dal firmarlo?

Comment: Semplicemente è che, quando mi dedicavo alla fisica, trovavo sempre molto divertente parlare o sentire parlare dell'articolo di Alpher, Bethe e Gamow; e il tuo nome mi ha fatto ricordare quei bei momenti.

Comment: @Charo :) Scusa, non avevo capito minimamente ti riferissi al mio nickname...

Comment: @AlephBeth conosci parole in altre lingue che, tradotte, soddisferebbero i criteri indicati?

Comment: @Easymode44 in effetti no. Immagino che in molte lingue sintetiche (per esempio in tedesco) sia possibile comporre dei termini atti allo scopo e che non risultino troppo astrusi

Comment: @Easymode44 Per esempio: *Rückzugsnotwendigkeitsbewusstsein* (ted., conio mio, ma *Rückzugsnotwendigkeit* è attestato)

Comment: Bè esiste la parola desistenza, anche se più che una virtù credo sia un atteggiamento nel desistere appunto a compiere una determinata azione.

Comment: In francese, usiamo "retenue" in quest'occasione. "ritegno" in italiano ?

Answer (score 0):

Entrambe le circostanze che citi fanno buon uso della saggezza, perché presuppongono la capacità di valutare la situazione ed agire di conseguenza: pur senza essere una virtù in senso proprio, la saggezza è sicuramente associabile ad una virtù, perché presuppone equilibrio e buon senso da chi la esercita.
Perciò è questo il campo in cui mi muoverei.

Una rapida scorsa ai [sinonimi](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/saggezza_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) di “saggezza” offre un vasto campionario di alternative, di cui alcune mi paiono particolarmente indicate per i casi che proponi.

- Nel primo caso sicuramente “**criterio**” è la parola che stai cercando: il Devoto Oli infatti ne dà come definizione la “capacità di giudicare rettamente, assennatezza, buon senso”.
  E gli [esempi](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/criterio/) che trovi nella pagina del vocabolario Treccani (che pure ne dà una definizione identica) mi paiono soddisfare il tuo dubbio.
- Il secondo caso è invece un po’ più problematico: la parola che stai cercando è indubbiamente “**polso**”, che però sa di informale se non di gergale.
  Il Devoto Oli infatti ne dà questa definizione: “Cercare, conducendo abilmente la conversazione, di conoscerne le intenzioni; anche a proposito di indagine sommaria e non impegnativa su fatti, fenomeni, situazioni”.
  È indiscutibile che in battaglia un comandante difficilmente ha notizie precise ma può contare solo su informazioni frammentarie, probabilmente confuse, e quindi deve prendere una decisione su dati insufficienti, “di pancia”: si trova quindi in una situazione assimilabile all’”indagine sommaria” della definizione.

Tuttavia, se vuoi una parola più ricercata, credo che “**assennatezza**” sia quella che cerchi, anche se non scarterei il “**criterio**” già visto.
Lascerei invece da parte “accortezza” o “avvedutezza”, che pure mi sembrano buone ma sono anche più adatte ad uno storico o commentatore successivo, che può giudicare sulla base delle piene informazioni e pure delle conseguenze delle azioni.

Se invece si tratta di ritirarsi, mettiamo, da una discussione, credo che “**buon senso**” sia quello che fa al caso tuo.
Ma il “buon senso” solitamente va bene con tutto: il guaio è che ce n’è sempre meno in giro.

Comment: In che senso il D.-O. dà la definizione “cercare etc.”? “Polso” è un nome, non un verbo. In ogni caso, non colgo il nesso tra il “polso” e il fatto di desistere. Al limite, ma anche quello non mi convince molto, avere il polso di una situazione sarebbe un prerequisito per capire come affrontarla (ed eventualmente, fra le varie possibilità, abbandonarla). Comunque vedo solo un nesso molto vago. Mi sfugge qualcosa?

Answer (score 0):

Io propongo *la temperanza*, come quella descritta dall'omonima carta dei Tarocchi.

In genere si descrive riferendosi alla moderazione, e quindi all'equilibrio tra la spinta a continuare a battersi, e la scelta di ritirarsi, appunto.